# Precedence of the concat operator and float identifier '.' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, T_DNUMBER)

Tags: php

I recently created an answer on SO and I became aware of what I think is a strange behaviour in PHP which I never noticed due to my (the following) coding style:

```
$var = 1;
echo "test string ". $var+1 ." example";
```

This works fine, however if I remove the space between `1` and `.`:

```
echo "test string ". $var+1." example";
```

It will give me the `T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING` parse error and in this case expecting a `','` or `';'` which is quite incorrect.

And yes.. it will work like so:

```
echo "test string ".($var+1)." example";
```

---

The problem I'm having with this is that the error message is that it does not reflect the underlying issue of what it specifically wants where most other messages are straight to the point and correct.

While I did not initially expect floating points to be the cause of this I still have a hard time understanding why the float operator takes precedence over the concat operator in the following scenario:

```
var_dump( .1, 1, 1., 1.0);
var_dump( 1.."a", "a"..1, 1.0."a");
```

> float(0.1), int(1), float(1), float(1)
> string(2) "1a", string(4) "a0.1", string(2) "1a"

Now I understand that arithmetic operators should go before string operations but here is the part I just don't get:

`".1` and `1."` should indicate that `.` is a concat operator and `1.1` should indicate that `.` is an identifier for a float. Instead they both give parse errors.

PHP is a language that is not picky when it comes to variable types:

```
var_dump(1 + 1.); // float(2)
var_dump(1. + 1); // float(2)
```

You can simply use `+ 1` to add to a float, why parse `1.` as a float at all? The parse error occurs on the next token, in which it expects a digit and not even allowing it to be a concat operator.

So my question is, why does the PHP lexer throw so much emphasis on float identification and *if* `echo 1."test"` would output `1test` could it break currently existing code?

> I've edited the question to clarify what I meant in the first place due to the negative rep I was getting. The currently accepted answer is still very much valid because I needed a way to verify php code without using `eval()`

Comment: Thats because `PHP` is expecting a floating point because you have a point right next to an `integer`. The string `1."` is not a valid floating point, hence the error

Comment: https://eval.in/646594 .   this `$var+1.` is taken as type conversion  in php and hens one  `.` missing error is given.

Comment: what i meant to say that `$var+1.` worka as type conversion and just after that parser getting " example" (string) and so it's giving error

Comment: @DarkBee While your comment holds marred, PHP explicitly states it is expecting a `','` or `';'`, not a float. I would not expect the parser to differentiate a float to a string by a mere space. `$var+1."` or `$var+1.232` while `$var+1.232."2323"` would make sense for an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1.` refers to the floating point number `1.0`. So what you wrote is lexed as:

```
echo "test string " . $var + 1.0 " example";
```

The string `" example"` is a `T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING` token. The parser isn't expecting one immediately after a floating point number.

You can check this with `token_get_all()`:

```
php > var_export(token_get_all('<?php echo "test string ".$var+1." example";'));
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 379,
    1 => '<?php ',
    2 => 1,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 328,
    1 => 'echo',
    2 => 1,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 382,
    1 => ' ',
    2 => 1,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 323,
    1 => '"test string "',
    2 => 1,
  ),
  4 => '.',
  5 => 
  array (
    0 => 320,
    1 => '$var',
    2 => 1,
  ),
  6 => '+',
  7 => 
  array (
    0 => 318,
    1 => '1.',
    2 => 1,
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    0 => 323,
    1 => '" example"',
    2 => 1,
  ),
  9 => ';',
)
php > print token_name(318);
T_DNUMBER
php > print token_name(323);
T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING
```

Note that `1.` shows up as one token, `318` (`T_DNUMBER`, double number).

Comment: So the priority would seem that it is applying the `.` to convert the value to a floating point number for arithmetic (not an operator), so `+` does have priority. I would never have had expected that floats where causing this issue as normally, I would capture them directly to variables..

Comment: @Xorifelse There is no priority issue here. The priority of the operators is applied when the program is syntactically correct, here there is a syntax error. `1.` is a floating point number, no string concatenation is involved. `1 .` is an integer followed by the string concatenation operator. `1."abc"` is a number followed by a string, no operators between them (syntax error). The same for `1. "abc"`. `1 ."abc"` is a number followed by the concatenation operator followed by a string. The same for `1 . "abc"`

Comment: @axiac That is what I meant by "(not an operator)", however there is a distinct difference between `1."` and `1.1`, where `1."` would state `.` is an operator and where `1.1` would make it a float. Hence, the confusion of the shortsightedness of the PHP interpreter, but understandable.

Comment: `1.` is a valid representation of a real number. Also `.1`. PHP doesn't parse them as the integer `1` and the concatenation operator. Other languages also parse these code fragments as valid floating point numbers. If you need it to be parsed as a number and the concatenation operator just squeeze a space between them (or use parentheses).

Comment: @Xorifelse It is theoretically possible that the parser could see that `T_DNUMBER` followed by `T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING` doesn't match any of the parse rules and therefore backtracks and tries treating `1.` as an int followed by string concat, however the PHP parser is split into different lexing and parsing steps, and the lexer can't get feedback from the parser to try a different lex, so once the lexer decides `1.` is a float, it's stuck that way, even though it could have parsed as an int and string concat.

Answer (score 0):

let me tell you, even your statement:
`echo "test string ". $var+1 ." example";` 
may not work expectedly.
It may print `1 example` instead of **`test string 2 example`**.

you may also find it useful

```
var_dump(1) gives `int 1` and
var_dump(1.) gives `float 1` and as expected
var_dump(1.0) gives `float 1` as answer
```

Reason for the unexpected result: 
  in `"test string ". $var+1 ." example";` 
first "`test string`" (a string variable) is concatenated to `$var` and makes result `string 1` (a string) and then it is added(**not concatenated**) to 1 making php change the type of `**string 1**` (string) to **int** thus it will become 0 and then added to 1 resulting in 1 (0+1=1). Then 1 (from int to string converted again) is added to `example` (a string) resulting in `1 example` (a string).

Use parenthesis to avoid such type changes 
 as in you last statement`enter code here`

```
echo "test string ".($var+1)." example";
```