# Validating a floating value in PHP

Tags: php

I started learning PHP to do some pet project, and I am trying to get this around my head on how to validate a valid float or double in PHP

Supposed I have this code in HTML that ask for interest rate

```
<input type="text" name="interest" size="5" >
```

In My PHP code, I wanted to validate if this is a valid interest rate:

```
<?php       
    $interest = $_POST['interest']
    //isset - empty test (not- shown)
    if(!is_numeric($interest) && is_float($interest)){
        print "<p><span class='error'>Interest should be numeric</span></p>";
    }
?>
```

I have my is_numeric()  test first then I coupled it with the is_float() test but when I enter "1." (note the "." after the number) it should catch this but apparently not.  I am not sure why "1." is a valid floating variable in PHP.

Comment: I suppose `$interest` is `$_POST['interest']`…? Then it's a *string*, and therefore not a `float`.

Comment: @deceze, Yes correct. $interest is $_POST['interest']

Comment: You could probably use some form of regex for acceptable characters or use preset values from a <select> dropdown.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, I am thinking of looking at regex next though I happen not to reach that far on my reading yet.  However, I am looking for php functions on how to do this validation.  This is actually my "Hello PHP" app but I already am having some problem wrapping this concept around my head.

Comment: @MarkEstrada I suggest you do, since what you're trying to use now and with the answers given below, you may not have a choice, or as I previously stated, to use a dropdown `<select>>` with preset values. However, another option here would be to use `ctype_digit()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php - There are examples in there. As stated by deceze in a comment, to use `\d+\.\d+` and the thing about 1.0. That's the best that I can offer. I hope you get your solution, *cheers*.

Answer (score 3):

Since POST or GET data will always be a string, `is_float` will always be `false`. The easiest way to deal with that is to use methods specifically designed for it:

```
$interest = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'interest', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
if (!$interest) {  // take care here if you expect 0 to be valid
    print 'Nope';
}
```

See http://php.net/filter_input.

Comment: would this work? -  if (!$interest || $intrest==0){// code

Comment: Rather `if ($interest === false || $interest === null)`.

Comment: @deceze, Not sure why but I tried your code.  The 'Nope' is not printed though.  I did print the $interest, what happens is that the "1." only becomes "1" after running through the filter_input.  Not sure why.

Comment: Well, for all intents and purposes `1.` is a valid float and the result will be the `float` value `1`. How much stricter do you need your validation to be and why? @Mark

Comment: @deceze Technically you are correct, but in the place where I am, a "1." is normally not a good "interest" value for common user so I am looking on how this is properly validated in PHP.  Of course I can use javascript to validate at the client side, but I just wanted to explore PHP and how to handle such scenario.  This is actually my first PHP page so I am exploring all possible solution.

Comment: @Mark FWIW, being lenient in what you accept is usually not a bad idea. "1." may technically be incorrect, but there's only one thing it can mean, "1.0", and as long as you sanitise that on the server there should be no issue. If you really require `\d+\.\d+` input… well, use that regex for validation.

Comment: @Mark Also: beware that floats are **inherently imprecise**. If you need precision, don't convert them to an actual float, but keep them as string.

Answer (score 2):

Use PHP built-in function

```
filter_var("your float", FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had a question why PHP picks up the `1.` as a float as well, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631924/concat-operator-float-identifier-precedence-in-php-t-constant-encapsed-string) for more information.

There might be 1 reason why the code is failing, and that is because a any data retrieved from the http header (post, get, cookie) is a string type.

`is_float()` checks the type, not the content of the variable where `is_numeric()` only checks the value. However, you can try to convert the value by doing the following:

```
$interest = $_POST['interest'];

if(isset($interest)){
  if(is_numeric($interest) && !is_float($interest + 0)){
    echo "$interest is a integer";
  } else {
    echo "$interest is not an integer";
  }
} else {
  echo 'Value not posted';
}
```

If the value of `$interest` is a float, it stays a float. If it is a string that cannot be parsed as a float, it will convert it to 0, in which `is_float()` will return false because it is not a float. In short, now it will only except integer values.

You could also use the `filter_var()` method explained in [deceze's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40019813/4982088) post.

Comment: I am still new to PHP, I am checking out the link you posted and I must admit that I was a bit lost.  My readings have not yet reached that far.  I tried deceze post but it still does not resolved my problem.  Please see my comment there.  Thanks Mate though, I will keep on reading.

Comment: @MarkEstrada The the code in this answer, works for me and so does the code from deceze for that matter. What PHP version are you running?

Answer (score 1):

i know this is too late.
but solution i implemented:

```
function isFloat($floatString)
{
   return (bool)preg_match('/(^\d+\.\d+$|^\d+$)/',$floatString);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Another option

```
if( strpos( $interest, '.' ) )
{
    print "<p><span class='error'>Interest should be numeric</span></p>";
}
```